# what is the variable name that stores a POST when done through jquery .ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when a form is submitted regularly via POST the contents of the values of the form are stored in $_POST but then the jquery .ajax function is used on an .submit what is the variable used to retrieve the data in the php file that processes the form?

Comment: can you show your relevant jquery code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue reading HTTP request body from a JSON POST in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php)

Comment: If you are submitting to a PHP page via `.ajax` POST, the variables are retrieved as $_POST.

Comment: @mario I don't think the OP is trying to read the request body. Sounds like form variables - so not a duplicate of the post you cited.

Comment: @jk: Well, maybe and no. Then it would be just a different duplicate. Like [Why can't I get my JSON Data posted using AJAX in my PHP file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285451/why-cant-i-get-my-json-data-posted-using-ajax-in-my-php-file)

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery `$.ajax` function takes a `type` parameter in the options, which sets whether the request should be done via `post` or `get`. It defaults to `get`.

If it's set to `get`, you can get to the info in PHP via the `$_GET` superglobal. On the other hand, if you set it to `post` (which is probably what you want), you can get to it via `$_POST`.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  type: 'post',
  data: {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  success: function(data)
  {
    alert( 'We have data: ' + data.toString() );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you set for the `type` argument. The default is `get`.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",   <---- type  
  url: "some.php",
  data: {somevar:'var'}
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```