# Is jQuery .serialize() populate $_POST equivalently?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have a form that submits using  `POST` and I want to covert it to an ajax submission of the form.  When I use the `.submit` function with the `.ajax` function inside when I serialize the data fom the form is it going to be the same as just doing a `POST`

Some code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#optionsForm").submit(function(){
            var data= $("#optionsForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'filter.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                    }
            });
            return false;
    });
</script>

<?php
$html = "";
$html .= "<div id='options'>";
$html .= "<form id='optionsForm' method='post'>";
foreach($selectValues as $key => $value){
    $title=new MODEL\String($key);
    $html.= "<fieldset class='optionsBox'>";
    $html.= "<legend>".$title->friendlify()."</legend><br/>";
    foreach($value as $option){
            $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='".$key."[]' value='$option'>".htmlspecialchars($option)."</input>";
    }
    $html.= "</fieldset>";
}
 $html .= "</select><input type='submit' value='submit'></form></div>";
 $html .= "<div id='tables'></div>";
```

Where I retrieve the data:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $filterValue=$_POST;
}
else{
    $filterValue="y";
}
```

Comment: you can see what your posting using the console tab in firebug.  just check view xml requests/errors.

Comment: 0.o  .... English please

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the variable name that stores a POST when done through jquery .ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538931/what-is-the-variable-name-that-stores-a-post-when-done-through-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

using `.submit(function)` just binds the ajax call to the submit, so you're probably leaving the page before the submit. You need to bind the ajax call to a click event on the submit button (as an example) and prevent the default submit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all form variables are serialized and sent in a POST request just like a form action="post" would submit.  Nothing to change on the back end except what output is passed from the form processing script, and how JavaScript should handle that output (i.e. Success, or Missing Field X)